# Devise with roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for authentication, Now in registration steps i want to add extra parameter, so I use `devise_parameter_sanitizer` like following

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :subdomain, :phone, :company, role_ids: []])
end
```

If I pass `role_ids` rails will automatically add roles for user, but I want to pass `role_names` instead of `role_ids` but its give me error

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'roles_name' for User.)
```

**Edited:**

```
models/user.rb
has_many :roles_user, dependent: :destroy
has_many :roles, through: :roles_user
```

Comment: `roles_name` is it a typo? shouldnt be `role_names` ?

Comment: I tried this also, no luck

Comment: Use rolify gem instead, ref link:
https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial

Comment: I dont want to use rolify gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the issue using foloowing way

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :subdomain, :phone, :company, role_names: []])
end
```

Add `role_names` in `devise_parameter_sanitizer`

And create new method with name `role_names=` in `models/user.rb`

```
def role_names=(role)
  roles = Role.where("name IN (?)", role)
  self.roles << roles
end
```

Comment: Yes, that's the proper way, but `self.roles = roles` is better, because you want **only** those roles that were passed to `role_names=`, but if you already have some roles set, you'll get `self.roles + roles`, and that will be unexpected. Anyway, can't imagine situation where we couldn't use `ids` :)

Answer (score 0):

Is `role_names=` defined on `User`? Do you have a database field or relation for `role_names`? Perhaps you simply have to rename `role_ids` column to `role_names` in your database.

Comment: Okay, `user has_many :roles`, and `:role_ids` is a method that is defined automatically, it's a getter and a setter. Why do you want to pass `role_names` as a parameter? You can display any attribute of `Role` on the form, but it's better to pass its id in params. Why do we always pass ids instead of names, titles, etc.? Because 1. it's 100% sure uniq 2. it's universal.

Comment: I agree with you @VasilyYudin

Comment: @VasilyYudin I am totally agree with you, But I have situation that I have to pass `role_names` instead of `role_ids`, Is there any way to get rid from this?